# Filling an array during compilation

Tags: c++, arrays, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I am trying to fill a char array using another constexpr char array during compile time, but I do not see how could I do this.

I am trying to emulate the following:

```
constexpr char arr1[N] = {/* Permutation of the numbers 0..N-1 */}
char arr2[N];
for(int i=0;i<N;++i)
    arr2[arr1[i]]=i;
```

but since I cannot return an array from a function, I do not know how to do this. Furthermore, I would like arr2 to be constexpr, since everything I need to compute it is known at compile time.

Any ideas about how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe a variadic template struct or function could help to generate some initializer list.

Comment: std::array has some limitations when it comes to constexpr, but yeah a simple struct could help you out.

Comment: @GuillaumeGris Of course, that does the trick!

Comment: I didn't use std::array in favor of regular arrays because of the problems it has with constexpr brackets operators and so. Anyways, I do not  think this would be any simpler using std::array, would it?

Comment: @Lezkus `std::array` allows some tricks, that you would need to implement yourself dealing with raw (regular) arrays.

Comment: @GuillaumeGris I already read that post, but I do not know how could I apply that to this problem, since I'm working with the index of the array here. I'm sorry, I'm new to TMP. If you could provide a sample code it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Try [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6084dc05b3c9289e)?

Comment: @Lezkus Mind to read the info popping up when tagging please.